# applying limit on stream conditionally - "stream has already been operated upon or closed"

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to apply `limit(Integer)` operation conditionally on a stream. My first approach was (tried to avoid terminal operations):

```
Stream<CustomerDetailsEntity> resultStream = aList
        // filter ...
        .stream().filter(c -> distinctPartnerNumber.add(c.getPartnerNumber()));
if (limit != null) {
    resultStream.limit(limit);
}
return resultStream.collect(toList());
```

This yields `stream has already been operated upon or closed` if limit is applied. Is limit a "terminal operation"?

Googling for `stream has already been operated upon or closed` suggests to use supplier but with this i can't reuse the supplier:

```
Supplier<Stream<CustomerDetailsEntity>> resultStreamSup =()-> aList
        // filter ...
        .stream().filter(c -> distinctPartnerNumber.add(c.getPartnerNumber()));
if (limit != null) {
    resultStreamSup = () -> resultStreamSup.get.limit(limit); //COMPILE ERROR, due to supplier is not final
}

...
```

So how to correctly apply limit conditionally (i want to avoid multiple return statements as usual)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of `limit()`.

It should be `resultStream = resultStream.limit(limit);` as the original stream isn't modified by the call.

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, truncated
>   to be no longer than {@code maxSize} in length.

Comment: silly me :-( - you are right (will accept as soon as possible)

Comment: @dermoritz It's an easy mistake to make when you're not chaining directly. I figured I'd make an answer since others might stumble here too.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the existing error of not reassigning the value, you could just modify the existing code to be more readable as:

```
return aList
        .stream()
        .filter(c -> distinctPartnerNumber.add(c.getPartnerNumber()))
        .limit(Optional.ofNullable(limit).orElse(aList.size())) // handling null here
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this solution i had before, i don't like to set limit if not needed (readability)